# not printing 5 letter long unicode

Tags: c++, unicode

```
strcpy(t, u8"\u1D004");
print("%s", t)
```

This is printing A4, taking 1D00 as symbol of A.
I want it to print like one at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_Musical_Symbols

Thanks,

Comment: From what header and/or did you use `print`?

Comment: We don't know what `print` is, and if it is capable of consuming the encoding of `t`. Incidentally, we don't know what encoding `t` is, so we don't know whether `strcpy` works as expected.

Comment: What is `print`? What is `t`?

Comment: @DevSolar: I was referring to the **contents** of `t`. They need to have an encoding that is compatible with `strcpy` and `print`. And that's not all: `print` (presumably) outputs a character string somewhere, and that somewhere needs to be prepared as well (must be capable of displaying Unicode strings, must have the respective fonts/glyphs installed).

Comment: @IInspectable: I wanted to point out the importance of "say what you mean, mean what you say", which can really bite you in this area especially. Out of interest -- do you know of *any* byte-based encoding that includes the null byte as something other as the string terminator? To my knowledge, you can feed *any* byte-encoding through `strcpy`. (And who's going around deleting my comments? Really strange...)

Comment: @DevSolar: (Offtopic): I'm not sure comments do get deleted. It looks more like stackoverflow is having serious issues (answers aren't sorted in the correct way either, for example). (Ontopic): I know that ANSI, ASCII, and UTF-8 do not use `NUL` except for zero termination. That doesn't mean that there isn't an encoding I'm not aware of where `NUL` can occur "in the middle" of a character string.

Comment: @IInspectable: Given that null bytes terminate C strings since quite some time (* cough *), I'd find that surprising. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: There are other programming languages and character string representations (Pascal/Delphi use counted strings without zero-terminators, for example). I'd be surprised to see a (byte-based) character encoding, where `NUL` can occur in the middle of a string. But the real point is: We don't know what data type `t` is and what character encoding it holds or is interpreted as.

Comment: @IInspectable: But *of course* the OP is compiling with warnings enabled and checked his code to be warning-free, so `t` *must* be of type `char *`. Surely? :-D

Answer (score 4):

Read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)!

```
\unnnn       universal character name
             (arbitrary Unicode value);          code point U+nnnn
             may result in several characters
------------------------------------------------------------------------
\Unnnnnnnn   universal character name
             (arbitrary Unicode value);          code point U+n
             may result in several characters
```

So:

```
strcpy(t, u8"\U0001D004");
//           ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> u8"\u1D004"
> ```

`\unnnn` is for **four hex digits only**. `1D004` are five digits, so it is interpreted as `'\u1D00'` (LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL A) followed by `'4'`. The program (as always) does exactly what you told it to do, not what you *thought* you had told it to do. ;-)

---

`\unnnn` may be used to specify characters in the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) only, with the noteable exceptions of:

- surrogate pairs (0xd800 - 0xdfff)
- C0 and C1 control characters (0x00-0x1f, 0x7f-0x9f)
- characters from the basic source character set (printable ASCII-7 with the exceptions of `$`, `@` and the backtick)

For characters beyond the BMP (as in your case with BYZANTINE MUSICAL SYMBOL OXEIA DIPLI), use `\Unnnnnnnn` (for which the exceptions above apply as well).

---

The relevant part of ISO 14881-2014 (Standard for Programming Language C++, 2.3 Character Sets, paragraph 2):

> The *universal-character-name* construct provides a way to name other characters.
>
> ```
>     hex-quad:
>         hexadecimal-digit hexadecimal-digit hexadecimal-digit hexadecimal-digit
>
>     universal-character-name:
>         \u hex-quad
>         \U hex-quad hex-quad
> ```
>
> The character designated by the universal-character-name `\UNNNNNNNN` is that character whose character
>   short name in ISO/IEC 10646 is `NNNNNNNN`; the character designated by the universal-character-name `\uNNNN`
>   is that character whose character short name in ISO/IEC 10646 is `0000NNNN`. If the hexadecimal value for a
>   universal-character-name corresponds to a surrogate code point (in the range 0xD800–0xDFFF, inclusive),
>   the program is ill-formed. Additionally, if the hexadecimal value for a universal-character-name outside the
>   *c-char-sequence*, *s-char-sequence*, or *r-char-sequence* of a character or string literal corresponds to a control
>   character (in either of the ranges 0x00–0x1F or 0x7F–0x9F, both inclusive) or to a character in the basic
>   source character set, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: So the OP continued to elude us, and the code does not print `A4` at all, it prints `ᴀ4`!